# Mapping to SQLAlchemy Table using a class with overwritten __new__ method

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, sqlalchemy

I have a custom class which inherits from Python's built-in `datetime.date` class:

```
# types.py

from datetime import date

class Date(date):
    def __new__(cls, *args, isExceptional: bool = None, **kwargs):
        if len(args) == 1 and isinstance(args[0], date):
            self = super().__new__(
                cls, args[0].year, args[0].month, args[0].day, **kwargs)
        else:
            self = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        if isExceptional is not None:
            self._isOff = True if self.isoweekday() in (6, 7) else False
            if isExceptional:
                self._isOff = not self._isOff
        else:
            self._isOff = None
        return self

    @property
    def isOff(self):
        return self._isOff

    @isOff.setter
    def isOff(self, value: bool):
        if self._isOff is not None:
            raise AttributeError(
                "'isOff' can be set only when it is currently undefined, i.e. None"
            )
        else:
            self._isOff = value
```

In a word `Date` resembles the built-in `date`, with an additional `_isOff` attribute as well as its accessors. Its constructor accepts as arguments either a standard `date` object or whatever acceptable for the original `date` constructor, along with an extra keyword-only one in order to manipulate `_isOff` value.

This class basically works, as

```
test = Date(2019, 9, 15)
print(test.isoformat(), "; isOff:", test.isOff)
test = Date(2019, 9, 15, isExceptional=False)
print(test.isoformat(), "; isOff:", test.isOff)
test = Date(2019, 9, 15, isExceptional=True)
print(test.isoformat(), "; isOff:", test.isOff)
```

gives me:

```
2019-09-15 ; isOff: None
2019-09-15 ; isOff: True
2019-09-15 ; isOff: False
```

On the other hand, I have a MariaDB table:

```
CREATE TABLE `date` (
    `date` DATE NOT NULL,
    `isOff` BIT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`date`)
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

I want to do SQLAlchemy mapping between them. I can't figure out the "Declarative" way, so I tried classical mapping, like this:

```
# orm.py
import sqlalchemy as ORM
date = ORM.Table(
    'date',
    ORM.MetaData(),
    ORM.Column('date', ORM.Date, primary_key=True),
    ORM.Column('isOff', ORM.Boolean)
)

# types.py, after the Date class definition
from . import orm
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper
mapper(Date, orm.date)
```

With above, `test = Date(2019, 9, 15)` gives me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\data\work\newsys\newsys\types.py", line 39, in <module>
    test = Date(2019, 9, 15)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given
```

I guess the `__init__()` mentioned in the error message comes from SQLAlchemy's mapping mechanism, since there's no `__init__()` defined in my class nor in the standard `date` class. Other than this, I can't figure out what's going on... what's that "1 positional argument" supposed to be and what are supplied as those 4?

How can I map them, with minimal modification to my Date class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please be aware that calling `mapper` on `Date` abd `orm.date` will change your `Date` class with SQLAlchemy's internally used meta-class. If you then also overwrite `__new__` you will get into a conflicting situation.

It seems SQLAlchemy tries to provide you with a default `__init__` implementation. I'm not sure why that is, but it is not problematic if you also overwrite `__init__`. As you don't need special handling there it is ok to just put the following into your class.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
    pass
```

A quick test showed that it won't crash after that.

Comment: The solution is easy: Don't overwrite the `__new__` method.

Comment: May I overwrite __init__() ?

Comment: Wait a minute. I'm currently debugging your example.

Comment: Thank you so much. And since there's an extra keyword-only argument in `Date.__new__()`, its `__init__` has to be like this: `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): pass`, otherwise there'll be `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument`